# rails render table of array indicies

Tags: ruby-on-rails

an action defines

```
@weeks = [1..@weeks_total + 1]
```

in the view, recalling the array

```
<%= @weeks.class %> 
<table>
  <% @weeks.each_with_index do |week, index| %>
    <tr><td><%= week %></td>  <td><%= index %></td></tr>
  <% end %>
</table>
```

the class is noted properly `Array` but the expected rendering of individual elements of the array is not happening as expected. the enumerable is not returning each individual item, instead returning the array

```
1..22   0
```

What is incorrect with the above approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@weeks` contains an array that's true, but the array contains one element which is a range `1..@weeks_total + 1`.

The solution is to get rid of the enclosing array `[]`.

```rb
@weeks = (1..@weeks_total + 1).to_a
```

Or if you don't mind `@weeks` to be a range. With `each_with_index` it will behave the same way as an array.

```rb
@weeks = 1..@weeks_total + 1
```